# Сериализация ForeignKey в Django REST API generics.ListAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Как вывести все поля модели в relationships?

Сейчас так:

```
"relationships": {
            "category": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "Category",
                    "id": "2"
                }
            }
        }
```

А нужно так:

```
"relationships": {
        "category": {
            "data": {
                "type": "Category",
                "id": "2",
                "slug": "test",
                "name": "Test"
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код `serializers` и `views`.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, дописать в сериализатор соответствующие поля.

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ('type', 'id', 'slug', 'name')
```

И в классе представления, соответственно, прописать соответствующий сериализатор

```
from your.path.to.serializers import YourSerializer


class YourView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = YourModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = YourSerializer
```